# In sympy, simplify an expression using a canonical commutation relation

Tags: python, sympy, physics

I have a [ladder operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method) â, which satisfies this [commutator relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) with its own adjoint:

> [â, â⁺] = 1

In sympy I have written this code:

```py
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import *

a = Operator('a')
ad = Dagger(a)

ccr = Eq( Commutator(a, ad),  1 )
```

Now I need to expand and simplify an expression like this:

> (â⁺ + â)⁴

If I just use `((ad + a)**4).expand()`, sympy doesn't use the commutator relation. How do I simplify the expression *while using* the canonical commutator relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any built-in way to do it, so I wrote a very basic algorithm for it. It's used like this:

```py
((ad + a)**4).expand().apply_ccr(ccr)
```

Result

> 3 + 12 a⁺ a + 4 a⁺ a³ + 6 a⁺² + 6 a⁺² a² + 4 a⁺³ a + a⁺⁴ + 6a² + a⁴

.

There is an optional argument called `reverse` which would rearange the expression to be `a` first and then `a⁺`. This is necessary to overcome the limitations of sympy which doesn't let you to specify the `Commutator` in a different order [[source]](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/commutator.html).

---

This is the implementation of `apply_ccr`:

```py
from sympy.core.operations import AssocOp

def apply_ccr(expr, ccr, reverse=False):
    if not isinstance(expr, Basic):
        raise TypeError("The expression to simplify is not a sympy expression.")

    if not isinstance(ccr, Eq):
        if isinstance(ccr, Basic):
            ccr = Eq(ccr, 0)
        else:
            raise TypeError("The canonical commutation relation is not a sympy expression.")

    comm = None

    for node in preorder_traversal(ccr):
        if isinstance(node, Commutator):
            comm = node
            break

    if comm is None:
        raise ValueError("The cannonical commutation relation doesn not include a commutator.")

    solutions = solve(ccr, comm)

    if len(solutions) != 1:
        raise ValueError("There are more solutions to the cannonical commutation relation.")

    value = solutions[0]

    A = comm.args[0]
    B = comm.args[1]

    if reverse:
        (A, B) = (B, A)
        value = -value

    def is_expandable_pow_of(base, expr):
        return isinstance(expr, Pow) \
            and base == expr.args[0] \
            and isinstance(expr.args[1], Number) \
            and expr.args[1] >= 1


    def walk_tree(expr):
        if isinstance(expr, Number):
            return expr

        if not isinstance(expr, AssocOp) and not isinstance(expr, Function):
            return expr.copy()

        elif not isinstance(expr, Mul):
            return expr.func(*(walk_tree(node) for node in expr.args))

        else:
            args = [arg for arg in expr.args]

            for i in range(len(args)-1):
                x = args[i]
                y = args[i+1]

                if B == x and A == y:
                    args = args[0:i] + [A*B - value] + args[i+2:]
                    return walk_tree( Mul(*args).expand() )

                if B == x and is_expandable_pow_of(A, y):
                    ypow = Pow(A, y.args[1] - 1)
                    args = args[0:i] + [A*B - value, ypow] + args[i+2:]
                    return walk_tree( Mul(*args).expand() )

                if is_expandable_pow_of(B, x) and A == y:
                    xpow = Pow(B, x.args[1] - 1)
                    args = args[0:i] + [xpow, A*B - value] + args[i+2:]
                    return walk_tree( Mul(*args).expand() )

                if is_expandable_pow_of(B, x) and is_expandable_pow_of(A, y):
                    xpow = Pow(B, x.args[1] - 1)
                    ypow = Pow(A, y.args[1] - 1)
                    args = args[0:i] + [xpow, A*B - value, ypow] + args[i+2:]
                    return walk_tree( Mul(*args).expand() )

            return expr.copy()


    return walk_tree(expr)


Basic.apply_ccr = lambda self, ccr, reverse=False: apply_ccr(self, ccr, reverse)
```

[(No rights reserved.)](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/)

Comment: Edit: added walkaround for [.copy() error on numbers](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18180)

Comment: This is brilliant, sympy should have the capability to simplify operator algebra