# Commutator algebra in SymPy

Tags: sympy, physics, quantum-computing

I am solving a commutator algebra in SymPy with the Hamiltonian

```
    from sympy import*
    a=Operator("a")
    ad=Dagger(a)
    b=Operator("b")
    bd=Dagger(b)

    H= ad*a + bd*b
```

Is there any way I can define commutation relations such as $[a,a^\dagger]=1$,
$[b,b^\dagger]=1$ and
$[a,b]=0$ ?

I want it such that if I calculate $[a,ad*b]$ I get $b$.
There is a code in answer to one of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523322/in-sympy-simplify-an-expression-using-a-canonical-commutation-relation)  but it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The function **apply_ccr** given by @m93a in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523322/in-sympy-simplify-an-expression-using-a-canonical-commutation-relation) should work. You might want to try something like the following,

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import *

com1 = Eq(Commutator(a, ad), 1)
com2 = Eq(Commutator(b, bd), 1)
com3 = Eq(Commutator(a, b), 0)

expr = (a*ad - ad*a) + (b*a + a*b) + (b*bd + bd*b) # example
print(expr) # −†+†+†++†+

for com in [com1, com2, com3]:
    expr = apply_ccr(expr, com)

print(expr) # 2+2†+2
```

Note it doesn't seem to work if your expression contains commutators.

Comment: It does not work for my particular case


    `com1 = sympy.Eq( Commutator(a, ad),  1 )`
   `com2=sympy.Eq( Commutator(a, b),  0 )`
    `com3=sympy.Eq( Commutator(ad, b),  b )`

    `expr=(Commutator(a,b*ad)).doit()`

    `print(expr)`
    `#-(-a*b*Dagger(a) + b*Dagger(a)*a)`

    `for com in [com1,com2,com3]:`
        `expr = apply_ccr(expr, com)`

    `print(expr)`
    `#-(-a*b*Dagger(a) + b*Dagger(a)*a)`

Comment: As mentioned, it doesn't seem to work when your expression contains commutators. You can perhaps just do `expr = a*b*ad - b*ad*a` instead.

Comment: When I apply `.doit()`, it expands the commutator, so it becomes the same thing as you have written.