# Setting canonical commutation relation for Operators with variable powers

Tags: python, sympy

I am using the apply_ccr method built as a response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523322/in-sympy-simplify-an-expression-using-a-canonical-commutation-relation) thread. The goal is for the program to be able to simplify the expression for arbitrary powers of the variable x. I can define the commutator for a single power of x like so:

```
com = Eq(Commutator(dx, x), 1)
```

This can successfully simplify strings of operators when there are no variables in the powers of x or dx, only integers. It achieves this by repeatedly commuting the variables. I am interested in commuting these Operators when x is raised to a power of s for some variable, typically a positive integer.

I have tried the following code:

```
s = Symbol('s')
k = Dummy('k')
x = Operator('x')
dx = Operator('dx')

com = Eq(Commutator(dx, x**s), s * (x**(s-1)))

expr = dx * x**s
expr.expand().apply_ccr(com)
```

But this does not simplify the expression given. I am aware that the apply_ccr function essentially just overrides the way sympy simplifies expressions to account for the desired commutation, but beyond that I do not know how the function achieves this and am therefore unable to duplicate/modify it to suit my problem.